# Onboard wait'n'click not working

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, accessibility, onboard

I have physical disability which makes moving with all my body very difficult, thus I use Onboard virtual keyboard to work with my PC using mouse only.

My problem is that after installation of Ubuntu Mate 18.04 I realized its wait'n'click function (I don't know its proper name, I use OS localized in my native language) is grayed-out and inactive.

[Wait'n'click function location (image is downloaded, the button of mine is greyed-out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOlkH.png)

This may sound stupid, but this little button saves my health. I work as programmer full-time and I need to rest my fingers often. Please, could someone help me to make it work?

Comment: I tested: It is greyed out also in my Lubuntu 16.04.1 (live) and 18.04 (installed). **In which (old?) version was it working (not greyed out)?** By the way, I think it is called 'Activate Hover Click' in the US English keyboard.

Comment: But I was able to activate hover click in standard Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 (live). That button is *not* greyed out, and after activating 'Hover Click' - 'Single Click' it started to work. Have a look at the 'Universal Access' setting. (It is possible that some of these features are not installed in Ubuntu MATE and Lubuntu.)

Comment: Remember to remove the tick from 'Hide hover click window' in the 'Onboard Preferences' window.

Comment: ... and the same (at least almost the same) works in standard Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 (live). But I don't know how to make it work in Ubuntu MATE. *Maybe someone, who is familiar with MATE can help you with it*, or you can use standard Ubuntu if your computer is powerful enough for it. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install mousetweaks? `sudo apt install mousetweaks`.

This must enable the dwell click option, other info here [Onboard hover/dwell click can' t be enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084212/onboard-hover-dwell-click-can-t-be-enabled/1088852#1088852).