# Onboard hover/dwell click can' t be enabled

Tags: onboard

I'm using lubuntu 18.04, after i reinstalled the OS the `onboard` dwell click key is grayed-out and cannot be used.
Also the mouse keys (in `onboard`) aren' t working anymore if i click one of them the mouse gets stuck on the key.
Using `dconf-editor` i tried with enabled/disabled dwell click (in the system) but nothing changes.
The dwell click is very important in this touch system certain things can be done only so.

How can i enable the `onboard` dwell click?
I reinstalled the OS once again but nothing. 
Also i remember that the super key had the ubuntu symbol instead of the writing "win" when it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install mousetweaks?
`sudo apt install mousetweaks`

With the touch you must tap quickly and shortly 3 times (in the last hold) and the right click is perfect. 
But you must have edited with `dconf-editor` the field `secondary-click-enabled`, in `org/gnome/desktop/a11y/mouse`.